# Find integer overflows caused by Java's unintentional implicit narrowing conversions

Tags: java, implicit-conversion

I have code that looks like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void doStuff() {
        int x;
        /* snip */
        x += Bar.getY();
        /* snip */
    }
}

public class Bar {
    public static int getY() {
        /* snip */
    }
}
```

I need to change `Bar.getY()` to return `long` instead of `int`. Due to Java's implicit conversion with `+=`, `doStuff` will continue to compile without errors or warnings, but will now contain an integer overflow bug. Is there any way to find all instances of this sort of implicit conversion in a Java codebase, to avoid unintentionally causing this sort of bug?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `x` is `int` and no matter what you try to do, it will eventually overflow if it has to. If you write `int x = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1000` it'll still overflow.

Comment: Jai I want to get a warning, so that I know I need to change `x` to long, or otherwise check for and handle the overflow.

Comment: why not just search for all references of `getY` ?

Comment: @JosephSible Then you need to search all instances of `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`, because the risk is always there no matter if there is method or not.

Comment: Scary Wombat There's a lot of them, so looking at each one manually would be tedious and error-prone.

Comment: Looks like Error Prone has a [rule](https://github.com/google/error-prone/blob/master/docs/bugpattern/NarrowingCompoundAssignment.md) for it.

Comment: shmosel That looks like exactly what I wanted. Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's code analyzer Error Prone has a rule for narrowing compound assignments: https://github.com/google/error-prone/blob/master/docs/bugpattern/NarrowingCompoundAssignment.md